# Pie menu gone! No, addon is not the correct one

Tags: pie-menu

I started using blender since 2.8 got out and been using the "standard" (or what i believe was the standard) pie menu since then. But my windows updated and neither .91 nor .92 seems to have the correct pie menu.  In fact since the update no pie menu appeared unless i active "tab for pie menu" in preferences, keymap. But that one gives me one i never seen before. Whats worse if i got to the preferences of my previous blenders that option was not ON. So im really lost on what happend here and how to get my workflow back to normal. And my friend google really seems to dislike this setting cuz i could not find ANYTHING on it. Picture is the one im used to.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The options are not the same, but the "Mode Selection" Pie menu is the one on your image and the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

[image]